# Create new column into dataframe based on values from other columns using apply function onto multiple columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy, apply

I am using apply function to create a new column i.e. ERROR_TV_TIC into dataframe based on existing columns [TV_TIC and ERRORS] values. I am not sure what I am doing wrong. With some conditions it works and with another it doesn't and throw error.

DataFrame:

```
ERRORS|TV_TIC
|2.02101E+41
['Length of Underlying Symbol for Option Contract is exceeding allowed limits(10 chars)']|nan
['Future Option Indicator is missing']|nan
['Trade Id is missing', 'Future Option Indicator is missing']|nan
['Trade Id is missing', 'Future Option Indicator is missing']|nan
```

**Code when it works:**

```
def validate_tv_tic(trades):
    tv_tiv_errors = list() 
    if pd.isnull(trades['TV_TIC']):
        tv_tiv_errors.append("Initial validations passed still TV_TIC missing")
    if pd.notnull(trades['TV_TIC']) and len(trades['TV_TIC']) != 42:
        tv_tiv_errors.append("Initial validations passed and TV_TIC is also generated but length is != 42 chars")
    return tv_tiv_errors if len(tv_tiv_errors) > 0 else np.nan

trades['ERROR_TV_TIC'] = trades.apply(validate_tv_tic, axis=1)
```

**Code when it doesn't work:**
Here now condition is on 2 columns of series and I am making sure that I am passing "&" and not "and"

```
def validate_tv_tic(trades):
    tv_tiv_errors = list()
    if pd.isnull(trades['ERRORS']) & pd.isnull(trades['TV_TIC']):
        tv_tiv_errors.append("Initial validations passed still TV_TIC missing")
    if pd.isnull(trades['ERRORS']) & pd.notnull(trades['TV_TIC']) & len(trades['TV_TIC']) != 42:
        tv_tiv_errors.append("Initial validations passed and TV_TIC is also generated but length is != 42 chars")
    return tv_tiv_errors if len(tv_tiv_errors) > 0 else np.nan

trades['ERROR_TV_TIC'] = trades.apply(validate_tv_tic, axis=1)
```

**Error I am getting**: ('The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()', 'occurred at index 3')

Error description with used "and"
[image: Error Screenshot 2]

Error description when used "&"
[image: Error Screenshot 2]

My gut feeling is saying that pd.isnull is somewhere causing problem but not sure.

Comment: Code that works is with 'and' and code that doesn't is with '&'.....

Comment: After replacing '&' with 'and' still getting same error

Comment: Which line of code gives the error?

Comment: screenshot attached. 3rd line

Comment: why did use the older code? (ur screenshot says that) Try it with `&` and then show the traceback

Comment: also post your dataframe. Just copy paste the result of `trades.head()` and post it

Comment: @Pygirl - Error screenshot attached for both "&" and "and"

Comment: Don't post pic. Post it in the form of text. Just drop some of the columns that is not needed for the code.

Comment: @Pygirl - Dataframe also added

Comment: @Pygirl - Added pipe separated

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/227755/discussion-between-pygirl-and-varun-vishnoi).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There was no problem with code. Problem exists with data inside dataframe.

column ERRORS was list of string and error was thrown when > 1 item exists as column value. So, I was getting error for line 3 and 4

```
ERRORS

['Length of Underlying Symbol for Option Contract is exceeding allowed limits(10 chars)']
['Future Option Indicator is missing']
['Trade Id is missing', 'Future Option Indicator is missing']
['Trade Id is missing', 'Future Option Indicator is missing']
```

After finding the root cause I changed the list to string where elements are separated by non-comma element and that works for me.

Changed my return statement of function validate_tv_tiv
from

```
return tv_tiv_errors if len(tv_tiv_errors) > 0 else np.nan
```

to

```
return ' & '.join(errors) if len(errors) > 0 else np.nan
```

and this created my dataframe column ERRORS as below:

```
ERRORS

Length of Underlying Symbol for Option Contract is exceeding allowed limits(10 chars)
Future Option Indicator is missing
Trade Id is missing & Future Option Indicator is missing
Trade Id is missing & Future Option Indicator is missing
```

Comment: Glad you were able to find out the solution :)